# How do I determine leaf nodes in ordered numbering (hierarchical) data?

Tags: pandas, tree, hierarchical-data

I have a column in a pandas DataFrame that represents a hierarchical classification structure, similar to numbered headings in a document.

As an example, the data format is like this:

```
class
'1'
'1.1'
'1.1.1'
'1.1.2'
'1.1.3'
'1.2'
'2'
'2.1'
'2.2'
'2.2.1'
'2.2.2'
```

My problem is that I'm looking for a way to represent this hierarchy within the data and to quickly determine which rows represent leaf nodes in the hierarchical tree. Notice that some leaves are at the second level and some at the third level.

My current approach has been to split the string on the periods and expand the columns. Then to set a MultiIndex with the resulting columns and sorting the index. The hierarchical structure is then represented but I'm unsure if there is a quick method to determine the leaves. I'm looking for an efficient solution that exists already and not a complex for loop which I'm probably capable of coding myself.

I've found a [package on CRAN for the R language called data.tree](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.tree/vignettes/data.tree.html) which has an 'isLeaf' function that seems to be perfect for my use case, but I can't seem to come by a similar solution for Python.

Here's the code to achieve what I've done so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
my_dict = {1: '0',
 2: '1',
 3: '1.1',
 4: '01.1.1',
 5: '01.1.2',
 6: '01.1.3',
 7: '01.1.4',
 8: '01.1.5',
 9: '01.1.6',
 10: '01.1.7',
 11: '01.1.8',
 12: '01.1.9',
 13: '1.2',
 14: '01.2.1',
 15: '01.2.2',
 16: '2',
 17: '2.1',
 18: '02.1.1',
 19: '02.1.2',
 20: '02.1.3',
 21: '2.2',
 22: '3',
 23: '3.1',
 24: '03.1.2',
 25: '03.1.3',
 26: '03.1.4',
 27: '3.2',
 28: '4',
 29: '4.1',
 30: '4.2'}
# Create Series from Dictionary
class_df = pd.Series(my_dict)
class_df.name = 'class'
# Split column on period and concatenate to DataFrame
class_df = pd.concat([class_df, class_df.str.split('.', expand=True)], axis=1)
# Name columns
cols = ['class', 'level_1', 'level_2', 'level_3']
class_df.columns = cols
level_cols = cols[1:]
#Standardise formate by padding zeros
class_df['level_1'] = class_df['level_1'].str.pad(width=2, side='left', fillchar='0')
# String split creates None values so drop those.
class_df = class_df.fillna('').set_index(level_cols)
class_df = class_df.sort_index()
```

Here's what the output looks like as a Dictionary, and a printed DataFrame.

```
{('00', '', ''): '0',
 ('01', '', ''): '1',
 ('01', '1', ''): '1.1',
 ('01', '1', '1'): '01.1.1',
 ('01', '1', '2'): '01.1.2',
 ('01', '1', '3'): '01.1.3',
 ('01', '1', '4'): '01.1.4',
 ('01', '1', '5'): '01.1.5',
 ('01', '1', '6'): '01.1.6',
 ('01', '1', '7'): '01.1.7',
 ('01', '1', '8'): '01.1.8',
 ('01', '1', '9'): '01.1.9',
 ('01', '2', ''): '1.2',
 ('01', '2', '1'): '01.2.1',
 ('01', '2', '2'): '01.2.2',
 ('02', '', ''): '2',
 ('02', '1', ''): '2.1',
 ('02', '1', '1'): '02.1.1',
 ('02', '1', '2'): '02.1.2',
 ('02', '1', '3'): '02.1.3',
 ('02', '2', ''): '2.2',
 ('03', '', ''): '3',
 ('03', '1', ''): '3.1',
 ('03', '1', '2'): '03.1.2',
 ('03', '1', '3'): '03.1.3',
 ('03', '1', '4'): '03.1.4',
 ('03', '2', ''): '3.2',
 ('04', '', ''): '4',
 ('04', '1', ''): '4.1',
 ('04', '2', ''): '4.2'}

                          class
level_1 level_2 level_3        
00                            0
01                            1
        1                   1.1
                1        01.1.1
                2        01.1.2
                3        01.1.3
                4        01.1.4
                5        01.1.5
                6        01.1.6
                7        01.1.7
                8        01.1.8
                9        01.1.9
        2                   1.2
                1        01.2.1
                2        01.2.2
02                            2
        1                   2.1
                1        02.1.1
                2        02.1.2
                3        02.1.3
        2                   2.2
03                            3
        1                   3.1
                2        03.1.2
                3        03.1.3
                4        03.1.4
        2                   3.2
04                            4
        1                   4.1
        2                   4.2
```

The expected output is that I want to return a Boolean Series with True for rows that are leaves in the hierarchical tree, and False otherwise.

Appreciate the help.